# Not able to find the elements when the page is loaded

Tags: java, selenium

while clicking the URL, the new page is loaded . after the page is loaded , I am not able to find out any elements in the page. I have used the below code . I am getting only no such element exception only. could you please help on the issue?

```
WebElement element7 = driver.findElement(By.id("linkid"));
if (element7.isEnabled())
{
    element7.click();
    System.out.println(" Report is selected");
}

testclass.waitForPageLoaded(driver); // using this method i have been waiting the page new page load. 



//find the elements in the new page . 
WebElement element8 = driver.findElement(By.id("cbPeriodType"));
if(element8.isDisplayed())
{   
    Select Periodtype = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("cbPeriodType`enter code here`")));     
    Periodtype.selectByValue("1");
    System.out.println("PeriodTypeSelected");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like element lookup is too fast. Use [explicit](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp) wait when finding the element. See a full list of ExpectedConditions [here](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html)

```
// find the elements in the new page . 
//WebElement element8 = driver.findElement(By.id("cbPeriodType"));
WebElement element8 = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
  .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("cbPeriodType")));

Select Periodtype = new Select(driver.findElement(element8 ));     
Periodtype.selectByValue("1");

System.out.println("PeriodTypeSelected");
```

Comment: it could not find out the element in the new page. could you please provide the alternative method to find the element.

Comment: Can you explain couldn't find? Possible stack trace. This is one of the best way to handle the elements takes time to load

Comment: After page load , it is not selected the value in the listbox.

Comment: Can you provide the error you are getting? Like NoSuchElement exception or such

Comment: Yes , after waiting long time , the webdriver is throwing the no such element exception only

Comment: Then verify the id is the same for the element after new page loaded

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76563/discussion-between-krishna-and-saifur).

Comment: Any one could help on this issue.

Comment: if the new page is loaded on new browser or new tab , can we use the same expected conditions else need to change other condition. could you please help me.

Comment: You can. But you have to switchTo newly opened window or tab

Comment: Yes Saifur, i have switched from parent window to child window and identified the element.